# How to force Latex to change from "A Appendix's name" to "Appendix A"

Tags: sectioning, appendices

I work on a article type document and I would like to force Latex to use "Appendix A" without giving a name in place of the simple "A" that it gives me when I start a new section in the appendices.

My example :

when I type this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
    % I write it because I would want to keep the (A.1) notation for 
    % equations' label for appendices

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
    blablabla

\begin{appendices}

\section{nameA}
    blablabla
\section{}
    blablabla
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I get this in the body of the document :

```
A nameA
blablabla
B 
blablabla
```

and in my toc I get

```
Appendix A nameA ... 
Appendix B
```

which is fine (as far as the toc is concerned)

But I would like that I got this in the body :

```
Appendix A nameA
blablabla
Appendix B 
blablabla
```

How to do this ?

Comment: Please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of your code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: @Red Hope it is enough

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just add the `title` option when including the `appendix` package:

```
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but how do I get *Appendix A: nameA*? Note the :.

Comment: @daaxix Do you know how to do that by now?

Comment: this does not work For KOMA-Script scrreport