# Changing "Chapter A" to "Appendix A" in TOC - Existing solutions don't work

Tags: appendices

I'm writing my thesis using \documentclass{harvard-thesis}

My desired result for TOC would be:

```
Chapter 1. 
Chapter 2.
Appendix A.
```

I use this to include the word "Chapter" in front of chapter numbers in TOC:

> \renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }

My appendix was shown in TOC as "Chapter A" instead of the desired "Appendix A":

```
>\appendix
>\renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix }
>\include{appendices/appendixA}
```

I have applied solutions from [How to force Latex to change from "A Appendix's name" to "Appendix A"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132972/how-to-force-latex-to-change-from-a-appendixs-name-to-appendix-a), [Changing “Chapter A” to “Appendix A” in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274200/changing-chapter-a-to-appendix-a-in-toc) as well as this patch:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect {Chapter }}{\ifappendix{Appendix }\else{Chapter 
}\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\appendixtrue}
```

None of them works. 
My current result for TOC is:

```
Chapter 1. 
Chapter 2.
Chapter A.
```

If I comment out the renewcommand that includes "Chapter" then Appendix A will show correctly:

```
1. 
2.
Appendix A.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Believe it or not, but the document class `harvard-thesis` is not unique: Several versions of LaTeX document class files with this name may be found on the Internet. Which version might you be using? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I'm using this version:
%  @LaTeX-class-file{
%     filename        = "harvard-thesis.cls",
%     version         = "0.4",
%     date            = "4 April 2012",
%     codetable       = "ISO/ASCII",

Comment: Can your version be downloaded from an online repository?

Comment: @Mico it's from sharelatex.com, https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/harvard-phd

Comment: MWE in zip file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xnUvvO0mbrY1S5O0DQIOABjjroeFyFml/view?usp=sharing
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Appendix chapters are considered chapters as well, specifically because that's what is written to the `.toc` file. To illustrate this, consider the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\appendix

\chapter{An appendix}

\end{document}
```

Here's what the `.toc` looks like:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}A chapter}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {A}An appendix}{5}
```

Note that each `\contentsline` entry corresponds to an entry in the ToC and they're all considered `chapter`.

In order to fix your problem, you can still update `\cftchappresnum` in your preamble, but write an update to this macro as soon as you execute `\appendix`. Here's how you can update `\appendix` to do this automatically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}% Just for this example

\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \oldappendix
  \addtocontents{toc} % Update \cftchappresnum within the .toc
    {\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Appendix }}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\appendix

\chapter{An appendix}

\end{document}
```

Now your `.toc` resembles:

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}A chapter}{3}
\renewcommand {\cftchappresnum }{Appendix }
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {A}An appendix}{5}
```

Each `\contentsline` entry is still a `chapter`, but `\cftchappresnum` was updated at the appropriate time within the `.toc` to print an `Appendix`  prefix for your appendix `\chapter`s.

Comment: that doesnt work for me. The result remains the same.

Comment: My tex file: https://pastebin.com/3kcCCwbx

Comment: @user148110: Are you getting errors? If so, what errors? I don't have all the files inside your sample code, so I can't compile your code.

Comment: Here is the zip file. Thank you for your help! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xnUvvO0mbrY1S5O0DQIOABjjroeFyFml/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

This works!

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
\addtocontents{toc}{%
\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
}%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}  
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{chapter}.\Roman{section}} 
\setcounter{chapter}{0}  

\include{chapters/chapter1}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\include{appendices/appendixA}
```